# How can I change all ids in my sql table sequentially?

Tags: mysql

I have about 1000 entries in my database:

```
id      name
 0      elephant
 0      snake
 0      monkey
....
```

I want no to change all ids afterwards. So that it looks like this:

```
id      name
 1      elephant
 2      snake
 3      monkey
....
```

How can I achieve this with SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to leverage an auto increment column, in a new table, then insert your previous content into that table.  First, create a new table with an auto increment id:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable (
    id INT AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255)
);
```

Now insert your old table into the new one:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (name)
SELECT name FROM oldTable;     -- you may select multiple columns here
```

Two potentials drawbacks here are that now you have an old table that might need to be deleted, and also the order assigned to the names would be arbitrary.  But in absence of logic for how to assign the IDs, this approach seems reasonable.

Comment: what if I have not only "name", but also other values in my table like "age" and "category". How can I copy all into the new table?

Comment: @Jarla You may select any number of columns, it doesn't change anything.  Just leave out the auto increment column, so that MySQL will fill it in for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the step by step solution for your problem, hopefully, resolve your issue.

```
mysql> create table dt1(id int,name varchar(20));
mysql> insert into dt1 values(0,'elephant');
mysql> insert into dt1 values(0,'snake');
mysql> insert into dt1 values(0,'monkey');
mysql> select * from dt1;
+------+----------+
| id   | name     |
+------+----------+
|    0 | elephant |
|    0 | snake    |
|    0 | monkey   |

mysql> update dt1 x join (select id,name,@r:=@r+1 as new_id from dt1,(select @r := 0)r) y on (x.name = y.name) set x.id = y.new_id;
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from dt1;
+------+----------+
| id   | name     |
+------+----------+
|    1 | elephant |
|    2 | snake    |
|    3 | monkey   |
```